# Finding the text of a div elememt where only ids are unique using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to keep a list of all divs with same class name i.e mod. For this I have sorted the list based on ascending ids. Hence I am looking for those ids whos internal div contains class title with text "Hello1" .

Here is the Structure

```
<div class="mod" id="mod23" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello1</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="mod" id="mod27" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello2</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
<div class="mod" id="mod25" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello1</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="mod" id="mod29" >
      <div class="content" >
       <div class="hd" >
         <div class="title">Hello2</div>
           <ul class="list"></ul>
           <ul class="buttons">
             <li class="help"></li>
             <li class="show" ></li>
             <li class="close"></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Here is the code I have tried to come up with which is not working

```
myarray is a sorted list of unique id number.        
     for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
    {


 $('#mod'+myarray[i]).each(function(index) {   

      $('div.title:contains(Hello1)').each(function(index) {

       alert('found at ' +i);
    });
    });
      }
```

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do. Do you want an alert for each div containing the text 'Hello1'?

Comment: I have tried to clarify myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `for` loop and:

```
$('#mod'+myarray[i]).each
```

You can use `starts with` selector like this:

```
$('div[id^="mod"]').each(function(){
  // this iterates over all divs with id starting like "modNUMBER"
});
```

*But* I assume this is what you are looking for:

```
$('div.title:contains("Hello1")').each(function(){
  var id = $(this).closest('.mod')[0].id;
  alert('Found in div with id: ' + id);
});
```

Comment: Please can you see the changed problem. Actually inside the unique id there are various nested divs. I want to check in them for the class title and text. Actually i want to know by index which one contains Hello1